# Azure Data Factory v2 "Invalid value for property 'type'" when running pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-rm-template, azure-data-factory

I have manually created an ADF v2 pipeline in the editor and it works correctly.

I exported this to an ARM template, with the only changes to the generated script I made are to replace the parameters('factoryName') with variables('factoryName') (as I want to use a derived name for the factory instance). I have also tried re-creating the pipeline using the generated json and parameters file, however the same problem still exists.

Whenever I attempt to run the pipeline I get the error:

*Invalid value for property 'type'* with absolutely no details that I can use to work out what the problem is. The error code is just *'BadRequest'*

Using the validator in the ADF portal shows that there are no validation issues with my configuration.

I have seen another [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754827/adf-v2-failure-when-using-bool-variable) that suggested that the Boolean data type was incorrect, I have tried changing these to boolean as well as Bool, however the error persists.

The task is a simple copy task that will copy from one Azure SQL database into another Azure SQL database, using a stored procedure on the destination database to perform an upsert.

I have re-created the ARM template twice in the ADF editor, both times have generated the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was migrating data from MariaDB to Azure. Even I faced this issue for copy activity pipeline, I exported the pipeline made the environment changes, imported the ARM template and when I tried to run get this same issue.
I tried to debug/search, but found nothing helpful.

The only conclusion I came up after debugging was if the data size is more then the conversion of the Data type is taking a lot of time and is not happening when we import the template.

But if we create the pipeline manually on the portal it runs fine without any error.

Do try to create the pipeline manually with similar db details of the failed pipeline, it will work fine.

And do let me know if you have found an alternative fix for this via the ARM template.