# Azure Data Factory Pipeline errorCode

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a relatively simple process set up in Azure Data Factory to copy, cleanse and process some log files from a chatbot which has been running fine until I recently started getting the following errorCode:

```
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "Unable to process expressions for action 'EvaluatefinaliseTSCRPTS': 'The function 'bool' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "finaliseTSCRPTS",
    "details": ""
```

I can't seem to identify the error in the ADF process despite going through the code for my process below:

```
"name": "SearchBot dailyTranscripts",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "MST Validation",
            "type": "Validation",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "teamsLogs",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "timeout": "0.00:00:30",
                "sleep": 10,
                "childItems": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Get MST-TSCRPTS",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "MST Validation",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "JsonSource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "wildcardFileName": "*.json",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    }
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "JsonSink",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings",
                        "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles"
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "JsonWriteSettings",
                        "quoteAllText": true
                    }
                },
                "enableStaging": false,
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "mappings": [
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['type']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['type']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['timestamp']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['timestamp']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['id']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['id']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['channelId']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['channelId']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['serviceUrl']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['serviceUrl']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['from']['id']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['from']['id']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['from']['aadObjectId']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['from']['aadObjectId']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['from']['role']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['from']['role']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['from']['name']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['from']['name']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['conversation']['conversationType']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['conversation']['conversationType']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['conversation']['tenantId']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['conversation']['tenantId']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['conversation']['id']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['conversation']['id']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['recipient']['id']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['recipient']['id']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['recipient']['name']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['recipient']['name']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['recipient']['aadObjectId']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['recipient']['aadObjectId']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['recipient']['role']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['recipient']['role']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['channelData']['tenant']['id']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['channelData']['tenant']['id']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['text']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['text']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['inputHint']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['inputHint']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['replyToId']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['replyToId']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['textFormat']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['textFormat']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['localTimestamp']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['localTimestamp']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['locale']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['locale']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['value']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['value']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['valueType']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['valueType']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['name']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['name']"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "path": "$['label']"
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "path": "$['label']"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "teamsLogs",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "transcriptsStaging",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "finaliseTSCRPTS",
            "type": "IfCondition",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "MST Validation",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Completed"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "activity": "Get MST-TSCRPTS",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded",
                        "Skipped"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "expression": {
                    "value": "activity('MST Validation').output.exists",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "ifTrueActivities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Combine TSCRPTS",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "JsonSource",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                    "recursive": true,
                                    "wildcardFileName": "*.json",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                }
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "type": "JsonSink",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings",
                                    "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles"
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "JsonWriteSettings",
                                    "quoteAllText": true
                                }
                            },
                            "enableStaging": false
                        },
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "transcriptsStaging",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "SearchBotDailyTranscripts",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "sourceFileName": "@concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'.json')"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Delete Staging",
                        "type": "Delete",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Combine TSCRPTS",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "dataset": {
                                "referenceName": "transcriptsStaging",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            },
                            "enableLogging": false,
                            "storeSettings": {
                                "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                "recursive": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Get monthlyTSCRPTS",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Combine TSCRPTS",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "JsonSource",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                    "recursive": true
                                }
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "type": "JsonSink",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "JsonWriteSettings",
                                    "quoteAllText": true
                                }
                            },
                            "enableStaging": false
                        },
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "SearchBotDailyTranscripts",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "sourceFileName": "@concat('2019-',formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'MM'),'-??.json')"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "SearchBotMonthlyTranscripts",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "sourceFileName": "@dataset().sourceFileName"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Get yearlyTSCRPTS",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Get monthlyTSCRPTS",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "JsonSource",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                    "recursive": true
                                }
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "type": "JsonSink",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings",
                                    "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles"
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "JsonWriteSettings",
                                    "quoteAllText": true
                                }
                            },
                            "enableStaging": false
                        },
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "SearchBotMonthlyTranscripts",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "sourceFileName": {
                                        "value": "@concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy'),'-??.json')",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "SearchBotYearlyTranscripts",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "sourceFileName": "@dataset().sourceFileName"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Copy MST-TSCRPTS",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Delete Staging",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "0.00:01:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "JsonSource",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                    "recursive": true,
                                    "wildcardFileName": "*.json",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                }
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "type": "JsonSink",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings",
                                    "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles"
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "JsonWriteSettings",
                                    "quoteAllText": true
                                }
                            },
                            "enableStaging": false
                        },
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "teamsLogs",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "transcriptsHistory",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Delete MST-TSCRPTS",
                        "type": "Delete",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Copy MST-TSCRPTS",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded",
                                    "Failed"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "dataset": {
                                "referenceName": "teamsLogs",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            },
                            "enableLogging": false,
                            "storeSettings": {
                                "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                "recursive": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "run learningList",
                        "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Delete MST-TSCRPTS",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded",
                                    "Failed",
                                    "Skipped"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "pipeline": {
                                "referenceName": "runLearningList",
                                "type": "PipelineReference"
                            },
                            "waitOnCompletion": true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "sourceFileName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "@concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'.json')"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
```

There is no expression 'EvaluatefinaliseTSCRPTS' and I can't find a 'bool' function either. The only hint I've found was a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754827/adf-v2-failure-when-using-bool-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You have an IF activity named "finaliseTSCRPTS", so "EvaluatefinaliseTSCRPTS" is most likely the internal name of the function that performs the IF condition check. The message seems to indicate that it cannot evaluate your expression "activity('MST Validation').output.exists".